# How do I convert "3 days" to "3" in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a one column filled with values like `3 days`, `6 days`, etc.

How can I strip out the text and force convert these to integers?

Comment: If the values you provided convert to 3 and 12, that leaves the unit (days, hours) unknown.  How will that be handled (or does it not matter?!). To answer these and other questions, I suggest you provide a complete before-and-after for your data, using more than just  two examples.

Comment: Do you want to use a function? And how will you find out if it is hours or days after stripping?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said in one column I have values with days and in the other hours.. so its OK if I lose the words entirely. I tried converting the columns to number format, but that did nothing.

Comment: if always a numeric then space, you can use a function like this (A1 is the cell): =LEFT(A1, FIND(" ", A1)-1)

Comment: Cool, how does this work across a column?

Comment: Honestly can't believe they don't have a dummy way to do this yet.. hah.

Comment: Just copy the cells below I guess. You can also write a simple UDF for this and use it with single function instead.

Comment: Bear in mind that you do not need to put the platform in your title, as it already exists as a tag.

Comment: Ok. Now I have the numbers I want.. but they are being handled like strings.. it there a "to integer" type method I can call on these cells? I need to do some calculations with these.

Comment: =LEFT(A1, FIND(" ", A1)-1)  * 1

Comment: Any calculation you will do with the result will cause it to be converted a numeric value.

Comment: Or if really need a converter function: =INT(LEFT(A1, FIND(" ", A1)-1) )

Comment: Finally: If you don't need a function and only need to change a column to numeric then you can use Text To Columns with Space delimiter. Then all your values will be listed as the first column and also as numeric. No function, no conversion... It all depends what you need.

Comment: That last thing you said right there. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways. it all depends what you actually need :) Glad it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert them "in-place", then select the cells and run this little macro:

```
Sub fixData()
    Dim r As Range, v As String, i As Long

    For Each r In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Text
        i = InStr(1, v, " ")
        If i <> 0 Then
            r.Value = Mid(v, 1, i - 1)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try substitute on a column next to you data:

```
=substitute(A1," days","") +0
```

Substitute replaces the string part  " data" with nothing (zls "") and adding zero returns a number.  This assumes your data is in col A.  Drag down the formula and voila

If you don't mind changing the data you could also just select it all hit ctrl+F choose find and replace find field is  " days", leave replace with blank and hit "Replace all"

Answer (score 1):

If its VBA, you could actually use the Val function to do this.
If A1 has the data and you want this integer value in A2

So something like:

```
Range("A2").value =  Val(Range("A1").value)
```

The returned value is actually a double. If a double isn't good enough,

```
Range("A2").value =  CInt(Val(Range("A1").value))
```

Hope that helps.